# Creating a preview effect for gallery images that closes when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a preview box that pops up when you click a gallery image and need to make it disappear when you click outside of it. I found many solutions but none work with my code. I think the problem is I may need a while loop but I tried several conditions and all were infinite.

This is the last solution I tried. The preview works but I can't get it to close when I click out.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/efaey1yn/)

```
$('.portPic').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-src2')) {
    $('#clickedImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src2'));
  } else {
    $('#clickedImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
  }
  $('#clickedImg').css('visibility', 'visible');
  $('#clickedImg').blur(function() {
    $('#clickedImg').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a similar thing with a pop-out menu, where the user clicks "off" the menu and it closes. The same can be applied here.

I used an overlay div which spans the whole screen (with a translucent opacity - maybe 0.6 black or similar; or whatever colour you want) which gives a nice modal effect. Give it an id - let's say `modal-overlay`.

You can put it static in your page code, and set the `display` to `none` and make it the full-size of the page (through a CSS class).

```
<div id="modal-overlay" class="full-screen-overlay"></div>
```

Set the `z-index` of the overlay to higher than the rest of your page, and the `z-index` of your popup to higher than the overlay. Then when you show your popup, also set the visibility of the `modal-overlay` to visible, too.

In your script code, put an event handler for when the modal div is clicked:

```
$('#modal-overlay').click(function() {
        $('#clickedImg').hide();
        $('#modal-overlay').hide();
    })
```

I would also use the `.hide()` jQuery method, which is easier than typing out the visibility.

Better still, if you have more than 1 thing going on (which you would with a modal overlay), wrap your "show/hide" of the popup in a `hidePopup()` or `closePopup()` method and call it onClick to save re-using code.

For effects when opening the popup/overlay, you can also use jQuery animations like `.fadeIn()` or `.slideDown()`. Use fadeOut and slideUp to hide.

These animations also perform the showing/hiding, so you wouldn't need to call `.hide()` or `.show()`.

Check out [this link](http://api.jquery.com/?s=animate) to jQuery's API documentation for animations. Very useful and a good read.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, I've just looked at your JSFiddle code. In your "#clickedImg"'s CSS, avoid setting the "visibilty"; and instead use "display: none". This enables the .show() / .fadeIn() and .hide() / .fadeOut() methods of jQuery to work properly, as it uses the "display" property to render the show/hide animation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a seperate div that is most likely fixed position that sits just one step lower (z-index) than your popped-up image. Attach a click handler to this div (overlay) and do your showing/hiding functions in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modal photo gallery. 
http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/ 
You can use this codepen code, too. SO is not letting me post the link here. So serach using thi "Bootstrap Gallery with Modal and Carousel".

Hope this helps..